# How to set Drush sql-sync not to clone users between @dev and @staging?

Tags: users, drush, staging

As I wrote in my previous [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/11531/2916),
I am using the following drush commands to synchronize development and staging environments.

```
drush rsync @dev @staging 
drush sql-sync @dev @staging
```

How to set up **drush sql-sync not to clone users between @dev and @staging** environments? 
I would like to have separate users (and passwords) on @dev and on @staging sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`drush sql-sync`](http://drush.ws/#sql-sync) has an option `--skip-tables-key` that allows you [`drushrc.php`](http://drush.ws/examples/example.drushrc.php) to skip tables during the synchronization.

In your drushrc.php you add this line.

```
$options['skip-tables']['staging'] = array('users', 'users_roles', 'roles', 'permission');
```

Your drush command line should look like the following.

```
drush sql-sync --skip-tables-key=staging @dev @staging
```

You've to be careful, as you've to skip all tables that had informations related to your users, including the tables used from third modules.

Comment: Thank you ! I did the way you suggested. I had some warning messages however I will try to find out maybe on drupal.org drush issue list: include(/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 454 of                                                               [warning]
/***/sites/default/settings.php).
include(): Failed opening '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in include() (line 454 of                                     [warning]
/***/sites/default/settings.php).

Comment: Its seems to be related with the module Domain Access, maybe a difference between your dev and staging ;)

Comment: You are right, it means rsync is not removing anything from staging directory tree it only copies when something is new, isn't it ?

Comment: Actually, the settings.php is by default exclude by the rsync, but you can change it by adding `drush rsync --include-conf @dev @staging` more info [here](http://drush.ws/#core-rsync)